# Amplify storage, AccessDenied for user with group: Access Denied when trying to .put on S3

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-amplify

I set up amplify storage as described here

https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/storage/getting-started/q/platform/js/#automated-setup-create-storage-bucket

I set access for auth and guest

everything for fine, I can upload files to s3 for all users except for user with group (i.e. admin users)

I tried to set permission for the user IAM role and group but it doesn't work

I found this thread https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/4055

it seems like a known issue, the only solution there is :

> To fix the issue, I ended up having to do this nastiness inside the s3
> cloudformation template... here's just a snippet from one of the
> policy's but you would need to update all of the "authenticated"
> policies (Would love to hear if this is advisable route or if there's
> a better potential solution as I'd have to remember to update this
> file every time I edit groups in my amplify setup)

but I don't understand what it means in practice

Please help

I found that if I change the `Restrict access by? · Individual Groups` it works for groups but not for guest

original
amplify update storage

```
? Select from one of the below mentioned services: Content (Images, audio, video, etc.)
✔ Restrict access by? · Auth/Guest Users
✔ Who should have access: · Auth and guest users
✔ What kind of access do you want for Authenticated users? · create/update, read, delete
✔ What kind of access do you want for Guest users? · create/update
✔ Select from the following options · Skip Question
✅ Successfully updated resource
```

groups

```
amplify update storage
? Select from one of the below mentioned services: Content (Images, audio, video, etc.)
✔ Restrict access by? · Individual Groups
✔ Select groups: · admin
✔ What kind of access do you want for admin users? · create/update, read, delete
✔ Select from the following options · Skip Question
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to select the 'both' option?

> ? Restrict access by? (Use arrow keys) 
> Auth/Guest Users 
> Individual Groups 
> ❯ Both

There you can config both of them
If not, in the file under storage/bucket/cli-inputs.json
you can also modify/check

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue because I added user Cognito Groups but did not update my storage configuration.

Perform these steps:

`amplify update storage`

Select the **Both** option and make your preferred configuration for each group that should have permission

`amplify push`